What is the purpose and difference of PGD, PUD, PMD, and PTE entries involved in paging?
As I understand it, a 48-bit virtual linear address's top 36 bits is split into four groups of 9 bits which each virtual linear address is indexed. Going from PGD, to PUD, to PMD, and then to PTE.
From what I gather, this is to increase efficiency so that there are not millions of page tables for each and every virtual address.
But how does this work exactly? How does each table of PGD's, to PUD's, to PMD's, and to PTE's differ? Or another way of asking is, why are there not 4 identical page tables instead of just 1 (as if each PGD entry is the same as the PUD entry it points to, and so on...)?
What is the purpose and difference of PGD, PUD, PMD, and PTE entries involved in paging?
